# JS file/function referenced in _Layout.cshtml is not working on another Views

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have some validation related functions that will be used on all my views and are located in an external JS file. I have added the JS reference in the _Layout.cshtml.

My understanding is that if file is referred into _Layout.cshtml, then it would be available for usage in the Views rendered in the layout. However, when I ran some another view for example and inspected it, I see the reference to the JS file "val.js" but it results with an error in the console (probably that error was a reason my validation is not working on another views):

And here is definition of my val.cs file:

```
(function ($) {
    var defaultOptions = {
        validClass: 'has-success',
        errorClass: 'has-error',
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest(".form-group")
                .removeClass(validClass)
                .addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest(".form-group")
            .removeClass('has-error')
            .addClass(validClass);
        }
    };

    $.validator.setDefaults(defaultOptions);

    $.validator.unobtrusive.options = {
        errorClass: defaultOptions.errorClass,
        validClass: defaultOptions.validClass,
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So any kind of help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: You do not appear to have included `jquery.validate.js` or `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in your layout

Comment: @StephenMuecke  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script> is included in my _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Not in the image you have shown. And the error message confirms its not (at least not before `validation.js` which it would need to be). But what are your trying to achieve with the script?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm trying to achieve that fields that I'm validating are red if validation is not satisfied, maybe I unned to include unobtrustive.js I'm gonna check it now

Comment: You do not need that script at all. You can just style the classes that are already added by the framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After stuggling for a few hours, I've found how to solve this, I simply added this to the bottom of my _Layout.cshtml

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/val.js")"></script>
```